# Handler method mappings with Spring 3.2.6

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, mapping

I'm trying to learn web app development with Spring MVC framework and I'm not completely clear about how controller mappings work. It will be better if I show my config and code first and then explain what I don't understand.

Here's mapping in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mapping in my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main/courses")
public class CourseController {
...
```

and mapping of the method in question in this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCourses(Model model) {     
...
```

As you can see, `value` attribute is set to empty quotes and this is the only way this mapping works. If I change `value` attribute to `"/"`, I get 404 error. I have other mappings in this controller that work fine, for example `value="/add"`. The only problem is when I try to map to the root of this controller.

Is `value=""` a valid value? Why `value="/"` doesn't work?

Comment: No one had similar issue?

Comment: so you want http://localhost:port/context/main/courses to be mapped to getCourses() right ??? Just remove the "Value" attribute from requestMapping annotation ,all GET request for that uri will be handled by getCourses() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@RequestMapping` used at the class level sets the base path mapping that all the handlers methods will resolved against.

In your example, that's

```
@RequestMapping("/main/courses")
```

When you specify another `@RequestMapping` on a method like

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
```

that is added as a path element. So the request would need to be to

```
/main/courses/add
```

If you have another like so

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

then you add a new path element but the element itself is empty. So the request needs to be to

```
/main/courses/
```

With a mapping like

```
@RequestMapping("")
```

there is no new path element, it's just the empty `String`. So the request would need to be to

```
/main/courses
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Is it ok to use `@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, or should I just omit the "value" attribute `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`?

Comment: @just_a_girl You can omit the value, they would be equivalent. If you have logging enabled at INFO level, you can see the path mappings generated.